# Datastax Enterprise 3.2 hive timeout exception

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hive, datastax-enterprise

I tried to run simple hive query through Datastax Enterprise, but it always fails with timeout (on small data set or even empty tables). I've got 4 nodes of m1.large on AWS (2x Cassandra & 2x Analytics). See below:

```
cqlsh:intracker> select count(*) from event_tracks_by_browser_date LIMIT 100000;

count
-------
15030
```

Then with hive:

```
hive> select * from event_tracks_by_browser_date where type_id=10;
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_201312292327_0003, Tracking URL = http://node3:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201312292327_0003
Kill Command = /usr/bin/dse hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=10.234.9.204:8012 -kill job_201312292327_0003
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 2; number of reducers: 0
2013-12-30 10:30:27,578 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2013-12-30 10:31:27,890 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2013-12-30 10:32:28,137 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2013-12-30 10:33:12,344 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_201312292327_0003 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Examining task ID: task_201312292327_0003_m_000003 (and more) from job job_201312292327_0003
Exception in thread "Thread-10" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while reading from task log url
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.errors.TaskLogProcessor.getStackTraces(TaskLogProcessor.java:240)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.JobDebugger.showJobFailDebugInfo(JobDebugger.java:227)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.JobDebugger.run(JobDebugger.java:92)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://node2:50060/tasklog?taskid=attempt_201312292327_0003_m_000000_1&start=-8193
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1626)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.errors.TaskLogProcessor.getStackTraces(TaskLogProcessor.java:192)
... 3 more
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 2   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

I checked system.log and it looks like sime kind of timeout appears.

```
INFO [IPC Server handler 6 on 8012] 2013-12-30 10:32:24,880 TaskInProgress.java (line 551) Error from attempt_201312292327_0003_m_000001_2: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOEx
ception: java.lang.RuntimeException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:97)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(HiveInputFormat.java:243)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:522)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:197)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:418)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:266)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:260)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.cql3.input.HiveCqlInputFormat.getRecordReader(HiveCqlInputFormat.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(HiveInputFormat.java:240)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingRecordReader$RowIterator.executeQuery(CqlPagingRecordReader.java:648)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingRecordReader$RowIterator.<init>(CqlPagingRecordReader.java:301)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingRecordReader.initialize(CqlPagingRecordReader.java:167)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.cql3.input.CqlHiveRecordReader.initialize(CqlHiveRecordReader.java:91)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.cql3.input.HiveCqlInputFormat.getRecordReader(HiveCqlInputFormat.java:94)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: TimedOutException()
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$execute_prepared_cql3_query_result.read(Cassandra.java:42710)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_execute_prepared_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1724)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.execute_prepared_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1709)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingRecordReader$RowIterator.executeQuery(CqlPagingRecordReader.java:637)
        ... 14 more
```

Cassandra CQLSH works with no problems... any idea??

Comment: What is your replication strategy for the cfs and cfs_archive keyspaces?

Comment: In both cases it's 'NetworkTopologyStrategy','Analytics': '1'

Comment: have you solved this issue ? i am having same problems

Comment: nope :( I abandoned using DSE and switched to plain Hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing your replication factor to 2 for Analytics.